# How to make the Animate jQuery method stop at end of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a customized carousel and it already has the following features:

1. You can move left and right with the mouse or by swipe on mobile/tablets.
2. You can move left or right with buttons.

However, the problem is that the buttons don't deactivate once the end of the div is reached. Instead, everything keeps shifting forever. See picture below:

[image]

Take a look at the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnkRw/2/

```
$("#left").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper").stop(true, true).animate({left: "-=125px"}, 500);
});
$("#right").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper").stop(true, true).animate({left: "+=125px"}, 500);
});
```

How can I deactivate the buttons once the end is reached? For example, when here:

[image]

The left button should deactivate since there are no more div's to show.

And, of course, the same for the right:

[image]

**The Goal: Deactive buttons when end is reached.**

Comment: why not disable based on the position of the wrapper since it moves each time you press a button?

Comment: What method would I use to deactivate a button? I am struggling with learning jQuery but I going to try the same way I learned CSS, just struggling through!

Comment: Maybe just hide it ?

$('#your-button').hide(), or .fadeOut(500) to animate it ?

If you want to really disable it, you could add the property disabled.
$('#your-button').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: make those divs into buttons and then like @Flo-Schield-Bobby said use `.prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: Ahum yeah didn't see it was only divs, sorry !

Comment: Thank you! What about something like, "if wrapper is in this position, remove #id class from the button's div."  and when it is back within range, add the #id back.  Does that sound silly or something that is worth trying?

Comment: The reason is because with buttons I can't style them as easy as divs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vnkRw/5/ - see if this helps.

Comment: when you reach the right end, its not that simple since the math or behavior depends of how much of the boxes are shown. and that depends on the windows width in this case. To make it work like its happening on the end of the left side you'd have to check if the last box is completely shown. if it is, then block the animation.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I will get to work with this new information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
   pos=slides=$(".wrapper > div").length;

   $("#left").click(function() {
    if(pos>3){$(".wrapper").stop(true, true).animate({left: "-=125px"}, 500);pos--;}
   });

   $("#right").click(function() {
    if(pos<slides){$(".wrapper").stop(true, true).animate({left: "+=125px"}, 500);pos++;}
   });

   $('.carousel').kinetic();
```

Comment: It's excellent! But for some reason, the kinetic plugin does not work with this.

Comment: But I put it in a document ready function and it works now!  Awesomeness!

Comment: But, when the divs ave moved all the way to the left, the kinetic plugin doesn't work. However, when the divs are moved all the way to the right, the plugin works fine. Any idea?

Comment: It is much better than what I had, but it doesn't fully work. Pay attention to seeing the first div maximum movement. You can't see the first div when all the way to the right. Vice versa is fine.

Comment: when its all the way to the left i see 1,2,3 and when its all the way to the right i see 5,6,7 is that now what you see? or is that not what you want?

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Except I also want to be able to drag them with the mouse. After thinking about it, your code is perfect. However, the entire wrapper div is being moved and the Kinetic plugin doesn't know that. So it prevents scrolling because it thinks that it is at the beginning. I have to find out what variables the Kinetic function uses and increment/decrement them accordingly after the left and right buttons are clicked.

Comment: does the kinetic thing snap them? or just leave them half in the wrapper?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't exactly understand your question. It's a really, really small jQuery plugin so I am trying to go through it, but I am not hopeful since I'm still a beginner. The Kinetic plugin is here:  http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/

Comment: I was hoping that the plugin would have options that you can move left and right with, but their options move 100% right or left and not through increments. The thing that gives me hope, however, is that the variable type is not boolean true or false, but is a string. So maybe they intended this more than just 100% left or right. I'm playing with it now

Comment: i was looking i think it would be easier to use the mouse down mouse up mouse position functions to work out the drag and move the wrapper in line as the mouse moves then onmouseup it would work out which snap its closer to and use the move animation to snap it to that

Comment: The only thing is that Kinetic works great with mobile and tables. This doesn't.  The other thing I noticed is that your code is based on the original viewport, but doesnt work when the viewport is changed. Check it out (my divs were responsive).

Comment: But no worries, I appreciate what you did, I will have to figure some stuff about and go from there. But I know a lot more than I did an hour ago =)

Comment: Wow, that is awesome! If we get this thing working fully, i'll give you a huge bounty my friend!

Comment: ok I've amended it more so that there is never a gap on the right side of the last slide after resize, it calculates the difference and moves the wrapper left

Comment: eg size the browser small then click the right button until you see the seventh slide and then resize the browser bigger and the seventh slide sticks to the right hand side

Comment: check out this question here!  Making progress!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121248/how-to-restore-link-functionality-on-android

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to consider when doing carousel, I'll just get you started.

1. Will all items be the same width
2. Will all items have same margins
3. Will the things above be variable

It we presume that all the things above are static, the idea is for the scroll to right to not happen if the left position of `wrapper` is `0`. And that's the easy part. For the other direction you have to take the number of all items, subtract the number of visible items (in your case 3) , multiply that by their width (including the margin) and all this providing all items are same width and with same margin .. and in the end you have to multiply that by -1, because your `wrapper`'s `left` position becomes negative number. And in the end, if `wrapper` reached that position, you should not scroll it.
A visualization of the above mini-wall of text:

http://jsfiddle.net/vnkRw/4/

Comment: You're right, this is why it works for one direction on the other answer and not for full-left extension. Thank you!