# how to stop animation once max width is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am working to make a slider that moves continuously while the users mouse is positioned over the arrow.  It works but it keeps moving even when the content has ended.

How can I make it stop so that the forward/back motion is disabled once all the slides have been viewed, or so that they can't go backwards when they are viewing the first slide?

My code is below - open to other methods to achieve this type of slider if what I have is bad.

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var timer;

                $("#leftarrow").hover(function() {
                    timer = setInterval(function() {slideLeft();}, 50);
                }, function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                });


            $("#rightarrow").hover(function() {
                    timer = setInterval(function() {slideRight();}, 50);
                }, function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                });



            function slideLeft() {
                $("img#background").stop().animate({
                    'left': '-=200px'
                }, 50);
                $(".mid").stop().animate({
                    'left': '-=20px'
                }, 50);
                console.log('alert');

            }

            function slideRight() {
                $("img#background").stop().animate({
                    'left': '-=200px'
                }, 50);
                $(".mid").stop().animate({
                    'left': '+=20px'
                }, 50);
            }


            });
```

Here is a fiddle with my slider: http://jsfiddle.net/rYYDv/

Comment: Look into the `step` function option of the `.animate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an additional if:

For slide left:

```
if(($(".mid").position().left) >= -500){ .. }
```

For slide right:

```
if(($(".mid").position().left) <= -10){ .. }
```

Disadvantage: You have to take care of the correct values manually. Which is not a problem, if the pictures don't change very often.

You should probably also add an additional else to ensure a correct final position (for the animate left property). But i think you get the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/rYYDv/2/

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough points to comment on this post; hence, I'm writing it down here -

Similar post: [How to make the Animate jQuery method stop at end of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111142/how-to-make-the-animate-jquery-method-stop-at-end-of-div)